# Python csv write module, need output into different rows instead of columns

Tags: python, list, file, csv

I am trying to get a list of files for a certain path in a csv file. I get the desired results but they are in a single row. How can the output appear in different rows.
My code is follows:

```
import csv  
import os  
path = raw_input("Enter Path:")  
dirList=os.listdir(path)  
csvOut=open('outputnew.csv','w')  
w = csv.writer(csvOut)  
w.writerow(dirList)  
csvOut.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call writerow multiple times to put the list into different rows.

```
for directory in dirList:
    w.writerow([directory])
```

(But in this case I don't see the need of using CSV...)